# Calculation geolocation distance returns NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am trying to work out the distance between a user and the coordinates below, I am not sure what I have done wrong, but I get the response 'NaN' (not a number)

HTML:

```
<h3>Come visit</h3>
<p>You're only <span class="distance"> </span>km away</p>
```

JS File:

```
// Location
if($('#content').hasClass('contact_page')) {
    var localSearch = new GlocalSearch();
    var sharp_hq = {
        lat: 53.639993,
        lng: -1.782354
    };
   // calculate the distance between me and thee
    var calculate_distance = function(location) {
        return Math.round(3959 * 1.609344 
       * Math.acos(Math.cos(0.0174532925 * location.y) 
       * Math.cos(0.0174532925 * sharp_hq.lat)
       * Math.cos((0.0174532925 * sharp_hq.lng) - (location.x * 0.0174532925))
       + Math.sin(0.0174532925 * location.y)
       * Math.sin(0.0174532925 * sharp_hq.lat)));
    };

    // geo location
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            //display in .distance <span>
            $('.distance', '.location').html(calculate_distance(initialLocation));
            $('p', '.location').css({ display: 'block' });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is value of initialLocation the expected one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sharp_hq = {
        lat: 53.639993,
        lng: -1.782354
    };
    // geo location
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            $('.distance').html( gc(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude,sharp_hq.lat,sharp_hq.lng).toFixed(2) );
            $('p', '.location').css({ display: 'block' });
        });
    }
} ) ;

/** Converts numeric degrees to radians */
if (typeof (Number.prototype.toRad) === "undefined") {
    Number.prototype.toRad = function () {
        return this * (Math.PI / 180);
    }
};

function gc(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    // returns the distance in km between the pair of latitude and longitudes provided in decimal degrees
    var R = 6371; // km
    var dLat = (lat2 - lat1).toRad();
    var dLon = (lon2 - lon1).toRad();
    var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                    Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) *
                    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = R * c;
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) object doesn't have .x or .y properties

Looks like you might still be expecting the [Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference) to work (it has been replaced by a wrapper for v3).

Instead of location.x/location.y use location.lat() for the latitude and location.lng() for the longitude.  Or make your own anonymous object with .x and .y properties (but don't expect it to be interchangeable with a google.maps.LatLng object).

**Note:** the Google Maps Javascript API v3 has a [library to calculate distance](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function called `google.maps.geometry.computeDistanceBetween()` that finds the distance between two latlng objects.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry

Replace the call to the `calculate_distance` function with

```
var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
  new google.maps.LatLng(sharp_hq.lat, sharphq.lng),
  initialLocation
) / 1000;
$('.distance').text(distance);
```

Returns the distance in meters so divide by 1000.

Comment: It calculates the distance between a user's location and another point.

Answer (score 0):

In your formula, the value of (0.0174532925 * sharp_hq.lng) - (location.x * 0.0174532925) could be < 0 causing NaN.

You need to pre-process it to 0 if it is <0 to avoid the exception.

I wish this resolves your issue without changing the whole formula.